# Is it possible to run Angular with Webpack, Sass, PHP, and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, angular, webpack, sass

I just want to know what the best practices are for getting a task runner to serve an Angular application that compiles Sass, reloads or "watches" PHP, and can query a MySQL database.

I have an app that uses Gulp to reload PHP and compile Sass, but I want to add Angular into the mix!

Any resources, comments, or questions are welcome!

Also, I followed the Webpack documentation on the Angular website (angular.io) but I was unable to deploy my application. Angular has just recently adopted webpack as a task runner/bundler.

Should I just continue to study Webpack or is there some type of workaround?

Thanks!!

-Donald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though its choice based but I would say stick to Webpack2. Its more powerful, widely used and getting better functionalities with time. Even most frameworks have CLI like angular-cli that use webpack2 under the hood. It also has the loaders to compile sass to css as you need. Checkout this github link that lists the steps to compile sass to css using Webpack loaders.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader

Comment: Thank you for your input! The sass-loader repository is a very good resource. The reason I'm not marking this as the answer (yet, though I did mark it as useful) is because I want to learn how to incorporate Angular. Yes, my question is about the framework, but I want to incorporate more than just Sass. I also need PHP and Angular (preferably 4 but 2 would work also). Again, thank you!!